# horizontal movement in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new in Unity and I'm trying to move a simple square on a classic 2D map (Super Mario like).

I use `addForce` to jump, it goes as planned.
But now, I'm trying to move my character horizontally.

First, I tried to use `tramsform.translation()`, I quickly notice that isn't the proper way, cause this method "teleports" the character, and if it moves too quickly, it can teleport behind a wall. I also try with `addForce`, but I want that my character has a constant speed, and it gives inertia, so it doesn't stop instantly when I release the key. I also try with `.MovePosition()`, but the character is shaking with this method (apparently, due to gravity).

So, whats the proper way to move a character (Rigidbody2D) horizontaly?

Here's my code with the different try:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class test : MonoBehaviour {
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Vector2 velocity;
    public float jumpforce;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Debug.Log(velocity);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpforce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("a")){ // move to the left
        rb.AddForce(-velocity * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        //rb.MovePosition(rb.position - velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        //transform.Translate(-velocity);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("d")){ // move to the right
            rb.AddForce(velocity * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            //rb.MovePosition(rb.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            //transform.Translate(velocity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might look into character controller scripts -- they're designed to mimic physical behavior like rigidbodies, while also supporting custom logic that tends to come up with character movement.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I use a setup like this:

```
Rigidbody2D rb;
[SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float LerpConstant;
//Other stuff here
FixedUpdate() {
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(h, rb.velocity.y);
    rb.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(rb.velocity, movement, LerpConstant);
}
```

Lerp simply means "take a Vector2 that is 'x' amount from A to B, and return it". So the code creates a movement vector that is your horizontal movement (user input), vertical movement (the vertical movement the rigidbody already has), and then lerp the current velocity to it. By modifying velocity directly, it ensures your movement will stay smooth and constant, so long as you know how to do it right.

Comment: Good advice about modifying velocity directly :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a "Physics" based movement then you should apply forces to the [Rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html). A benefit of acting on the rigidbody is that it will take into account colliding with objects (like walls).

[Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/moving-the-player) is a great intro tutorial (it's 3D but the same concepts apply for 2D). This is the code from that tutorial with some amendments to make it 2D:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;    // Here we set a float variable to hold our speed value

    private Rigidbody2D rb;  // This is to hold the rigidbody component

    // Start is called as you start the game, we use it to initially give values to things
    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();  // Here we actually reference the rigidbody.
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // We assign values based on our input here:
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        // Here we assign those values to a Vector2 variable.
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2 (moveHorizontal, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);    // Finally we apply the forces to the rigidbody
    }
}
```

We can alter the *manner* in which the force acts on the rigidbody by changing the `AddForce`.[ForceMode2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) parameter. For example, `ForceMode2D.Force` will

> Add a force to the rigidbody, using its mass.

`ForceMode2D.Impulse` will

> Add an instant force impulse to the rigidbody2D, using its mass.

which is better for things like jumping.

- Note - it is better to put physics-based method calls in `FixedUpdate`, not in `Update`, because of frame-rate dependency.
- Also note - as you are applying a force to an object, it will accelerate because you are acting on a mass (the rigidbody) and decelerate based on other forces ([friction](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html) etc.) If you want your player to slow to a halt instead of stop dead, think about the forces acting upon the player. Furthermore, if you apply a force to the rigidbody once per FixedUpdate, this will result in the constant speed you want if you choose `ForceMode2D.Force`as other forces acting in the opposite direction will balance it out (see below image - credit to http://www.school-for-champions.com/ for the image).

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Regarding the comment by rutter above, [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/2d-controllers) is an introductory tutorial on 2D Character controllers.